# Recursion Limit Exceeded in javascriptSerializer.serialize

Tags: c#, wpf, javascriptserializer

I'm using JavascriptSerializer to convert the list into string, but its not working and its throwing an error as `Recursion Limit Exceeded`. I have searched a lot but i didn't found any solutions to overcome this issue.

My conversion is like below

```
List<CustomType> _customValues= serializer.ConvertToType<List<CustomType>>(dictionary["CustomValues"]);
string CustomString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_customValues);
```

**EDIT**

My custom type is below

```
 public class CustomType
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get
            { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (this._name != value)
                {
                    this._name= value;
                }
            }
        }

        private double _mark;
        public double Mark
        {
            get
            { return _mark; }
            set
            {
                if (this._mark!= value)
                {
                    this._mark= value;
                }
            }
        }

        private int _id;
        public int Id
        {
            get
            { return _id; }
            set
            {
                if (this._id!= value)
                {
                    this._id= value;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

How can i convert that list into string?. 
How can i overcome this issue?.

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: Please post your CustomType class

Comment: What does the rest of your method look like that is doing the Serialization?

Comment: Are you setting the jsonSerialization element in your config file? Check the object level of that element. It might be set to something low like 1 or 2?

Comment: Based on some assumptions, I was able to run something similar to your code without any problems. This leads me to believe the result from `serializer.ConvertToType<List<CustomType>>(dictionary["CustomValues"])` is not returning what you're expecting or you've somehow included a non-simple type (e.g. Guid) in your class - but I can't know for sure without further information.

Answer (score -1):

Use a JSON Serializer that ignores circular references. `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` can't ignore circular references and will easily get stuck in recursion and reach recursion limit.

Comment: what is your proposal?